# Debugging a program using Valgrind - Detecting a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, oop, boost, boost-python

I have a class A and a class B which is derived from A :

```
class A
{
  public :
  A() { // Some code }
  virtual ~A(){}
  // etc
};
```

And here is my class B :

```
class B : public A
{
  public :
  B():A(){//Some extra code}
  ~B();
  // etc
};
```

The real code of A and B are quite long so I wouln't post it there, unless if it's necessary.

***My problem is that, in my main program :***

- When I instantiate A, there is no problem with it
- When I instantiate B, I can "play" with it (access to its members etc),
  but when the program is finished, I got a segfault.

***The segfault appears only when I have an instance of B.***

So, to find the location of my problem, I attempt to use Valgrind, but I'm quite stuck because I don't understand what Valgrind is displaying.

The output of Valgrind is quite long, but there's a scheme in it, and here is the result :

```
==13512== Invalid read of size 4
==13512==    at 0x852EE9D: __tcf_0 (in /usr/local/lib/libeikeotools.so)
==13512==    by 0x6AE15E9: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:56)
==13512==    by 0x84C3E72: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libeikeotools.so)
==13512==    by 0x4010739: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:252)
==13512==    by 0x6AE1258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==13512==    by 0x6AE12A4: exit (exit.c:104)
==13512==    by 0x6AC6ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
==13512==  Address 0x131e4d00 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==13512==    at 0x4C2C2BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13512==    by 0x664536E: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==13512==    by 0x73A3384: __tcf_0 (logwriter.cpp:32)
==13512==    by 0x6AE15E9: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:56)
==13512==    by 0x7301A72: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libeikeotoolsd.so)
==13512==    by 0x4010739: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:252)
==13512==    by 0x6AE1258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==13512==    by 0x6AE12A4: exit (exit.c:104)
==13512==    by 0x6AC6ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
==13512== 
==13512== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==13512==    at 0x4C2C2BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13512==    by 0x852EEB3: __tcf_0 (in /usr/local/lib/libeikeotools.so)
==13512==    by 0x6AE15E9: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:56)
==13512==    by 0x84C3E72: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libeikeotools.so)
==13512==    by 0x4010739: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:252)
==13512==    by 0x6AE1258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==13512==    by 0x6AE12A4: exit (exit.c:104)
==13512==    by 0x6AC6ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
==13512==  Address 0x131e4cf0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==13512==    at 0x4C2C2BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13512==    by 0x664536E: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==13512==    by 0x73A3384: __tcf_0 (logwriter.cpp:32)
==13512==    by 0x6AE15E9: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:56)
==13512==    by 0x7301A72: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libeikeotoolsd.so)
==13512==    by 0x4010739: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:252)
==13512==    by 0x6AE1258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==13512==    by 0x6AE12A4: exit (exit.c:104)
==13512==    by 0x6AC6ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
```

**EDIT 1 :** Here is my 'B' class :

HOGpython.hpp :

```
#ifndef HOGPYTHON_H
#define HOGPYTHON_H
#include "osell/cvaddenda/HOGDescriptor2.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "conversion.hpp"

#define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY

class  HOGpython : public eikeotools::CvAddenda::HOGDescriptor2
{

    public:

        // Constructeurs :
        HOGpython();
        HOGpython(PyObject* _winSize, PyObject* _blockSize, PyObject* _blockStride, PyObject* _cellSize, int _nbins, double _winSigma);

        // Destructeur :
        ~HOGpython(){ std::cout << " Destroying .." << std::endl;}

        // setters :
        PyObject*   get_winSize() const;
        PyObject*   get_blockSize() const;
        PyObject*   get_blockStride() const;
        PyObject*   get_cellSize() const;
        int         get_nbins() const;
        int         get_derivAperture() const;
        double      get_winSigma() const;
        int         get_histogramNormType() const;
        double      get_L2HysThreshold() const;
        bool        get_gammaCorrection() const;
        int         get_nlevels() const;

        // Setters :
        void    set_winSize( PyObject* o);
        void    set_blockSize( PyObject* o);
        void    set_blockStride( PyObject* o);
        void    set_cellSize( PyObject* o);
        void    set_nbins( int o);
        void    set_derivAperture( int o);
        void    set_winSigma( double o);
        void    set_histogramNormType( int o);
        void    set_L2HysThreshold( double o);
        void    set_gammaCorrection( bool o);
        void    set_nlevels( int o);

        // Méthodes d'instance :
        PyObject* compute(PyObject* img, PyObject* locations);
        PyObject* computeSubPix(PyObject* img, PyObject* locations);
        PyObject* computeGradient(PyObject* img);

};

#endif
```

And HOGpython.cpp :

```
#include "HOGpython.hpp"





// ==  Constructeur sans paramètres == //
HOGpython :: HOGpython():eikeotools::CvAddenda::HOGDescriptor2()
{}

// ==  Constructeur avec paramètres == //
HOGpython :: HOGpython(PyObject* _winSize, PyObject* _blockSize, PyObject* _blockStride, PyObject* _cellSize, int _nbins, double _winSigma)
    :eikeotools::CvAddenda::HOGDescriptor2( tupleToSize(_winSize),
                                            tupleToSize(_blockSize),
                                            tupleToSize(_blockStride),
                                            tupleToSize(_cellSize),
                                            _nbins,
                                            1,
                                            _winSigma,
                                            eikeotools::CvAddenda::HOGDescriptor2::L2Hys,
                                            0.2,
                                            false,
                                            eikeotools::CvAddenda::HOGDescriptor2::DEFAULT_NLEVELS)
{}

// ==  Getters == //
PyObject*   HOGpython::get_winSize()            const   {return SizeToTuple(winSize);       }
PyObject*   HOGpython::get_blockSize()          const   {return SizeToTuple(blockSize);     }
PyObject*   HOGpython::get_blockStride()        const   {return SizeToTuple(blockStride);   }
PyObject*   HOGpython::get_cellSize()           const   {return SizeToTuple(cellSize);      }
int         HOGpython::get_nbins()              const   {return nbins;                      }
int         HOGpython::get_derivAperture()      const   {return derivAperture;              }
double      HOGpython::get_winSigma()           const   {return winSigma;                   }
int         HOGpython::get_histogramNormType()  const   {return histogramNormType;          }
double      HOGpython::get_L2HysThreshold()     const   {return L2HysThreshold;             }
bool        HOGpython::get_gammaCorrection()    const   {return gammaCorrection;            }
int         HOGpython::get_nlevels()            const   {return nlevels;                    }

// ==  Setters == //
void    HOGpython::set_winSize(PyObject* o)     {winSize            = tupleToSize(o);}
void    HOGpython::set_blockSize(PyObject* o)   {blockSize          = tupleToSize(o);}
void    HOGpython::set_blockStride(PyObject* o) {blockStride        = tupleToSize(o);}
void    HOGpython::set_cellSize(PyObject* o)    {cellSize           = tupleToSize(o);}
void    HOGpython::set_nbins(int o)             {nbins              = o; return;}
void    HOGpython::set_derivAperture(int o)     {derivAperture      = o; return;}
void    HOGpython::set_winSigma(double o)       {winSigma           = o; return;}
void    HOGpython::set_histogramNormType(int o) {histogramNormType  = o; return;}
void    HOGpython::set_L2HysThreshold(double o) {L2HysThreshold     = o; return;}
void    HOGpython::set_gammaCorrection(bool o)  {gammaCorrection    = o; return;}
void    HOGpython::set_nlevels(int o)           {nlevels            = o; return;}



PyObject* HOGpython::compute(PyObject* img, PyObject* locations)
{
    //  Déclaration d'instances :
    cv::Mat im, pt;
    PyObject* ret;

    // Conversion :
    NDArrayConverter cvt;

    im = cvt.toMat(img);
    pt = cvt.toMat(locations);

    // Déclaration de vecteurs :
    std::vector<float> desc;
    std::vector<cv::Point> pts;

    //Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS;
    PyThreadState * m_thread_state;
    m_thread_state = PyEval_SaveThread();

    for(int i = 0; i < pt.rows; i++)
    {
        pts.push_back(cv::Point(pt.at<double>(i,0), pt.at<double>(i,1)));
    }

    eikeotools::CvAddenda::HOGDescriptor2::compute(im,desc,cv::Size(),cv::Size(),pts, false);

    PyEval_RestoreThread(m_thread_state);
    m_thread_state = NULL;
    //Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS;
    cv::Mat pointsMat = cv::Mat(desc);
    ret = cvt.toNDArray(pointsMat);

    return ret;
}


PyObject* HOGpython::computeSubPix(PyObject* img, PyObject* locations)
{
    //  Déclaration d'instances :
    cv::Mat im, pt;
    PyObject* ret;

    // Conversion :
    NDArrayConverter cvt;

    im = cvt.toMat(img);
    pt = cvt.toMat(locations);

    // Déclaration de vecteurs :
    std::vector<float> desc;
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> pts;

    //Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS;
    PyThreadState * m_thread_state;
    m_thread_state = PyEval_SaveThread();

    for(int i = 0; i < pt.rows; i++)
    {
        pts.push_back(cv::Point(pt.at<double>(i,0), pt.at<double>(i,1)));
    }

    eikeotools::CvAddenda::HOGDescriptor2::computeSubPix(im,desc,cv::Size(),cv::Size(),pts, false);

    PyEval_RestoreThread(m_thread_state);
    m_thread_state = NULL;
    //Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS;
    cv::Mat pointsMat = cv::Mat(desc);
    ret = cvt.toNDArray(pointsMat);

    return ret;
}

PyObject* HOGpython::computeGradient(PyObject* img)
{
    // Déclaration d'instances :
    cv::Mat im, grad, angleOfs;
    PyObject* listeRes;
    PyObject* grad_;
    PyObject* angleOfs_;

    // Conversion :
    NDArrayConverter cvt;
    im = cvt.toMat(img);

    //Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS;
    PyThreadState * m_thread_state;
    m_thread_state = PyEval_SaveThread();
    eikeotools::CvAddenda::HOGDescriptor2::computeGradient(im, grad, angleOfs, cv::Size(), cv::Size());
    PyEval_RestoreThread(m_thread_state);
    m_thread_state = NULL;
    //Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS;

    // Conversion :
    grad_ = cvt.toNDArray(grad);
    angleOfs_ = cvt.toNDArray(angleOfs);

    // Création d'une liste Python dans laquelle les deux résultats seront enregistrés :
    listeRes = PyList_New(0);
    PyList_Append(listeRes, grad_);
    PyList_Append(listeRes, angleOfs_);

    // Renvoie des données :
    return listeRes;

    }
```

Unfortunately, I can't show my class A (part of a framework), But I can tell that A does not cause any segmentation faults.

Just to sum up my code, I would like to make a wrapper of my class A for python, and as A contains some OpenCV objects, Boost.Python can't convert them automatically, so I created B derived from A, but with some conversion from opencv objects to Python objects.

To do the conversions, I have a conversion module that's working fine.
I would like to add something : Here is my main code that give me a segfault :

```
int main()
{
  HOGpython h;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you briefly summarize what your main code does?

Comment: The stack trace indicates that when deleting an instance of  std::string, the program attempts to access a block of memory that was freed.

Comment: Is the question how to make sense of the Valgrind output?  And/or perhaps why is a segfault occurring?  For the latter, can you please provide a [mcve]?  Removing potential noise (unused getter/setters, Boost.Python, etc.) may help simplify the problem.  Based on the Valgrind output, I would be suspicious of the destructor order of globals and statics within libeikeotools and libeikeotoolsd.

Comment: @TannerSansbury You are right, the problem came from these two modules, they can't coexist. One is a release module, and the other one is a debug module. So I reconfigured the hole thing, and it works now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem.. and it was nothing to do with my code.

The problem came from conflicting shared libraries, the framework I used was not well installed I guess.
I removed it, reinstalled completely, and everything is working fine.

Problem solved !

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a global objects' destructor (which is possibly a `std::string` or something which has some relationship with an `std::string`) gets called but either that object was deleted manually, either someone took ownership of that object and deleted it.

Please share more code with us, a logwriter class's source should not contain terribly sensitive data, and its presence might help actually identify the bug.

BTW, please make sure that `~B();` is actually has an implementation.

Comment: @ademstavux Thanks for the updated answer. Can you please let me know what is on line 32 in logwriter.cpp ? That's what's shown in the valgrind log. Also, just try to run your application via gdb, see if it gets you further.

Comment: Here is what's inside logwriter at line 32 :

 const std::string ColoredStdStreamWriter::color_codes_[] =
{ "\33[1;31m",
  "\33[0;31m",
  "\33[0;33m",
  "\33[1;34m",
  ""
};

Also, I tried with gdb but it gives me nothing worth to be interpreted.

Comment: Ok. Can you track all the usages of the `color_codes_` member in your application and see that it is properly handled (ie: no `C` style character handling, no passing in to char* functions, no code which feels dangerous, etc...)

Comment: Ok, I will try it. But I don't think the problem came from this : In my code, I'm not using logwriter.cpp

My class B inherite from a class that is declared in the framework where logwriter is used. But when I instantiate an object of the class A, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: @ademstavux I also see no reference to anything resembling any logginf, so possibly the only way it is used is that `eikeotools::CvAddenda::HOGDescriptor2::computeSubPix(im,desc,cv::Size(),cv::Size(),pts, false);` at some level which is not visible or the `eikeotools::CvAddenda::HOGDescriptor2::compute(im,desc,cv::Size(),cv::Size(),pts, false);
` or the  `eikeotools::CvAddenda::HOGDescriptor2` constructor or the application logic itself at some point references it.